# How to check if a string contains two asterisk characters?

Tags: java, string

We have a string input and the following combinations are valid (e.g. `sunday`, `*sunday*`, `sun*day*`, `*sun*day`, `su*nda*y`)
If it contains only a single asterisk, then it is a bad input.

So given the above input, how do I check to see if the string contains multiple asterisks.

Comment: It should be exactly two

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `String.matches` with a regular expression:

```
"^.*(?:\\*.*){2}$"
```

If you want *exactly* two asterisks:

```
"^[^*]*(?:\\*[^*]*){2}$"
```

Though for this task it might be simpler just to iterate over the string and count the asterisks.

Comment: Could anyone please explain this regular expression?

Comment: The first one could be described as: starts with any number of characters, then lookahead (twice) to find an asterisk followed by more characters.
The second could be described as: starts with anything besides asterisks, then look ahead (twice) to find an asterisk followed by anything else.

Comment: I think these have bugs in them, because they lookahead twice, but there's nothing preventing the lookahead to find the same thing twice. I think if you replaced the {2} with {45} it would continue to match strings that only had 1 or 2.

Comment: Also note that there's double backslashes which isn't part of regex, but is needed (i.e. in java) to get a blackslash into the regex engine to escape the asterisk.

Answer (score 9):

```
int asterisk1 = input.indexOf('*');
boolean hasTowAsterisks = asterisk1 != -1 && input.indexOf('*', asterisk1+1) != -1;
```

Edit: this solution assumed that the requirement was "has at least two asterisks".

Answer (score 4):

At least two ways:

- regex

  ```
  String regex = ".*\\*.*\\*.*";
  boolean valid = input.matches(regex);
  ```
- loop

  ```
  int asterisks = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i ++) {
      if (input.charAt(i) == '*') {
          asterisks++;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: You could remove the `.*` from the front and end of the regex and use `find()` instead. That might actually be a bit faster.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a non-regex alternative that works with any literal string:

```
public static boolean containsNoneOrTwo(String haystack, String needle) {
    int index = haystack.indexOf(needle);
    return (index == -1) ||
        haystack.indexOf(needle, index+1) == haystack.lastIndexOf(needle);
}
```

Essentially the algorithm is:

```
containsNoneOrTwo(haystack, needle)
   = haystack contains no needle OR
        haystack's second needle is also its last
```

Comment: And to modify it to check for *exactly two asterisk*, just change the third line to `return (index != -1) &&`.

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean hasTwoAsteriks(String str) {
int i;
if((i = str.indexOf("*")) != -1) {
  if ((i = str.indexOf("*", i+1)) != -1)
    return true;
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness (although several good answers have been provided, I like Mark's and Joachim's best), here are two versions based on [String.split(regex)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and [String.split(regex, limit)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

(Edit, bug fix:)

```
boolean containsAtLeastTwoAsterisks = ("_" + myString + "_").split("\\*", 3).length == 3;

boolean containsExactlyTwoAsterisks = ("_" + myString + "_").split("\\*").length == 3;
```

---

I wrote [a little benchmark](http://pastebin.com/vjwtfUzU) based on our answers (I know, benchmarks don't mean much, but they are fun, and mine is probably crap, I know.) Anyway, here are the results for a sample run:

```
*********************************************************************************

Testing strings with one or less asterisk

Processor: bhups
Finished. Duration: 40 ms, errors: 0

Processor: Bozho (loop version)
Finished. Duration: 33 ms, errors: 0

Processor: Bozho (regex version)
Finished. Duration: 806 ms, errors: 0

Processor: Joachim Sauer
Finished. Duration: 24 ms, errors: 0 <-- winner

Processor: Mark Byers
Finished. Duration: 1068 ms, errors: 0

Processor: seanizer
Finished. Duration: 408 ms, errors: 0

*********************************************************************************

Testing strings with exactly two asterisks

Processor: bhups
Finished. Duration: 14 ms, errors: 0 <-- winner

Processor: Bozho (loop version)
Finished. Duration: 21 ms, errors: 0

Processor: Bozho (regex version)
Finished. Duration: 693 ms, errors: 0

Processor: Joachim Sauer
Finished. Duration: 14 ms, errors: 0 <-- winner

Processor: Mark Byers
Finished. Duration: 491 ms, errors: 0

Processor: seanizer
Finished. Duration: 340 ms, errors: 0

*********************************************************************************

Testing strings with more than two asterisks (not all processors will be included)

Skipping processor bhups

Processor: Bozho (loop version)
Finished. Duration: 63 ms, errors: 0  <-- winner

Skipping processor Bozho (regex version)

Skipping processor Joachim Sauer

Processor: Mark Byers
Finished. Duration: 1555 ms, errors: 0

Processor: seanizer
Finished. Duration: 860 ms, errors: 0
```

Seems like non-regex is a lot faster than regex. That's what you'ld expect, I guess.

EDIT: fixed wrong winner. sorry, joachim

Comment: you're right, I found it myself just before reading your comment. fixed it.