# Filtering a string went wrong

Tags: java, string, if-statement

Consider we have the following set of String:

```
String text="Geeraertsb,∗,1";
String text2="bla bla";
String text3="in terms of &#1";
```

I would like to get those strings that do not contain either of `&` and/or "*". so that means only `text2" is of interest.

however if I use:

```
if(!text.contains("*"))
{
    //do something
}

if(!text3.contains("&"))
{
    //do something
}
```

it does enter the `if` statement while it should not. Any idea why?

Comment: the `∗` in your text seems to have another format and is not equal to the `*` that you are trying to find.

Comment: Seems like this is what you want: if(!text.contains("*") || !text3.contains("&"))

Comment: so how to fix this issue? this is kind of headache to me now.

Comment: @FastSnail no no, that is not the case. I just wanted to show that each string that contains a specific char, passes the if condition while the contain that char and should not go into the statement.

Comment: http://ideone.com/iaVgqJ

Comment: This can be a tricky job. You need to know the encoding your pdf file is using.

Comment: what are all possible encodings? so I check all manually in case it matches one of them with the pdf encoding.

Comment: [Please check below link having full information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350804/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-two-asterisk-characters)

Answer (score 1):

You're using different characters

`∗` is not equal to `*`

You may want to check that you're using the same set of characters for you `String` objects and your conditions.

Comment: How am I supposed to do it? what about `&`? same things happen for `&`.

Comment: @lonesome There seem to be no problem with `&`, I tried it on Eclipse and it works fine.

Comment: But it does not do the same for me.

Comment: @lonesome Then you should give us more details. You already asked a question earlier and I asked you to post your input. If you're not giving us details about your problem, there is no way we could solve it.

Comment: that is why i made this question with the input. in other question i showed that the input comes from a pdfbox object.

Comment: see it doesn't enter to if conditions http://ideone.com/iaVgqJ

Comment: @FastSnail I know but in my code it enters. that is why i am confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
Pattern mypat = Pattern.compile("[^a-z ]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher mat = mypat.matcher("Geeraertsb,∗,1");
boolean found = mat.find();

if (found)
{
   //code
}
```

The above code uses the regex approach in which you try to check if your string contains anything apart from the alphabets.

Comment: in my case it did not work. I am using [pdfbox](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjvs4Lj0sTLAhUFJKYKHa0gCegQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpdfbox.apache.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNEbaVW5mOPMt_Nmuv2qxj045bd76g) and the text comes from a text extracted from a pdf.

Comment: @lonesome probably text  has different characters but looks pretty similar.pdf files has different characters for exmaple `“` and `"` .when i copy codes from pdf .i see lot of errors because of that

Comment: @FastSnail the problem is when i insert this string into an XML file, the XML file corrupts because of these characters.